# In Android Studio, how make an item in the recyclerview open another activity when clicked?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-activity, onclicklistener, new-operator

I enter text in search text fields and then press submit.
The text is appended to a baseURL2 and sent.
The JSON is parsed and displays select objects in a recyclerview.This all works great.
Now I want to click a value that is in the recyclerview and append to another URL and send.
Then parse that response and display in a new activity.
It is an easy thing to ask but I am having issues when clicking an item in the recyclerview, nothing happens.
And everytime I get to this step, I break my code.

Tried adding click listener and I can see it react in the logcat.
But nothing happens on screen

Comment: You've described a general problem so vaguely no one can help you. But "handling RecyclerView item click" is a common question - search this site and / or the internet in general and you should find plenty of answers.